# Spring Trace Id and Span ID in GCP Cloud Run request log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud, stackdriver, spring-gcp

I am using spring cloud GCP logging and trace in my GCP cloud run application

```
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
<include resource="org/springframework/cloud/gcp/logging/logback-appender.xml"/>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STACKDRIVER"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

After adding this I can see that logs are grouped

[image]

Now I have two questions

1. Can we have the trace ID and and span ID printed in the request log it self.
2. After adding stack driver, the spring default console pattern is not shown. All the logs are printed in raw format. They do not have thread-name, span id, appName etc.

Can these two be achieved?

**Update**
Trying to enhance the log

```
@Component
public class NukTraceIdLoggingEnhancer extends TraceIdLoggingEnhancer {

  @Override
  public void enhanceLogEntry(LogEntry.Builder builder) {
    super.enhanceLogEntry(builder);

    LogEntry.Builder newDummyBuilder = builder;

    LogEntry logEntry = newDummyBuilder.build();
    Payload<?> payload = logEntry.getPayload();
    if (logEntry.getPayload() instanceof JsonPayload) {
      JsonPayload jsonPayload = (JsonPayload) payload;
      String content = (String) ((JsonPayload) payload).getDataAsMap().get("message");

      content = "abc" + logEntry.getSpanId() + ", " + logEntry.getTrace() + content;

      jsonPayload.getDataAsMap().replace("message", content);

      builder.setPayload(jsonPayload);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void enhanceLogEntry(LogEntry.Builder builder, ILoggingEvent e) {
    super.enhanceLogEntry(builder, e);

    LogEntry.Builder newDummyBuilder = builder;

    LogEntry logEntry = newDummyBuilder.build();
    Payload<?> payload = logEntry.getPayload();
    if (logEntry.getPayload() instanceof JsonPayload) {
      JsonPayload jsonPayload = (JsonPayload) payload;
      String content = (String) ((JsonPayload) payload).getDataAsMap().get("message");

      content = "XYZ" + logEntry.getSpanId() + ", " + logEntry.getTrace() + content;

      jsonPayload.getDataAsMap().replace("message", content);

      builder.setPayload(jsonPayload);
    }
  }


}
```

**logback-spring.xml**

```
        <configuration>
          <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
          <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

            

<property name="STACKDRIVER_LOG_NAME" value="${STACKDRIVER_LOG_NAME:-spring.log}"/>
                <property name="STACKDRIVER_LOG_FLUSH_LEVEL" value="${STACKDRIVER_LOG_FLUSH_LEVEL:-WARN}"/>

                <appender name="MY_STACKDRIVER" class="com.google.cloud.spring.logging.LoggingAppender">
                  <log>${STACKDRIVER_LOG_NAME}</log> <!-- Optional : default spring.log -->
                  <loggingEventEnhancer>abc.configuration.NukTraceIdLoggingEnhancer</loggingEventEnhancer>
                  <flushLevel>INFO</flushLevel> <!-- Optional : default ERROR -->
                </appender>

            <root level="INFO">
              <appender-ref ref="MY_STACKDRIVER"/>
            </root>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: I didn't catch your 1st question, and for the second, you mean you installed agent on the Compute Engine VM when you talk about "stackdriver"?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere 1. For this ask, in cloud run request log, can we print the span id and trace id in request it self
2. For the second question, I can see that logs are grouped and printed. But they are like raw, do not have thread name, class name etc. Can we define pattern? We have enabled stackdriver api in cloud project

Comment: For 1 and 2 I don't really understand the need. For me, the essential is done: you have the spanID and the traceID. Now you have to build a query that group and display the data as expected. You can use logs analytics for that (based on SQL language) https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/log-analytics#analytics

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere I was trying to modify the message body of the log to have custom message. Can you check my updated question? It does not print anything in logs may be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: The Cloud Logging service is pretty stupid: it trace anything that you put in the standard output. Your appender is correct for that: console appender. No problem. Then when you will log something, a log entry will be written with the log content, wrapped in a Google Cloud environment context. That's why, you will have a "textPayload" with your log, and the rest is standard GCP. Did you find something similar in Cloud Logging?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere . If you see my example, I was just trying add span text to each payload. Actually its not working. Am I doing right?

Comment: @Patan Since you are using a cloud logging agent you can specify your agent to convert the payloads to Json format. Logging agent then sends the logs written in structured format to cloud logging as the Json payload of log entry structure. Follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) for more information.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? I don't see a log.info of your payload. Is that your issue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere. The logs are not getting printed. I am trying to figureout, what could be the issue

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have updated the code in question. But logs are not there in cloudrun instance.

Comment: You are touching my limits in Java... Do you know if your logger is in synchronous or asynchronous mode? I mean, if the log written a small duration after the invocation? If yes, it's maybe a background process throttled by Cloud Run. Did you validate your code locally?